# Set Inner values in python dictionaries without declaring multiple empty dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pydash

Lets say I have a dictionary like

```
ship = {'AddNewShipmentV3': {'oShipData': {'ReadyDate': '2021-01-11T12:00:00', 'CloseTime': '2021-01-11T08:12:34', 'ServiceLevel': 'EC', 'ShipperName': 'Test 1/12/2021','SpecialInstructions': 'Invoice - RMA#S, 7800401086-GOOD EQUIP Pickup - DRIVER WILL NEED SHRINK WRAP FOR 2 PALLETS PLEASE CALL', 'Station': 'SLC', 'CustomerNo': '9468', 'BillToAcct': '9468', 'DeclaredType': 'LL'}}}
```

I want to create a new dictionary (b), by extracting ReadyDate value and store it as ReadyTime and CLoseTime value and store it in CloseDate. and I want to add these new key-value pairs to the starting of the dictionary. I tried this

```
def ready_date_time(a):
 b = {}
 b["AddNewShipmentV3"] = {}
 b["AddNewShipmentV3"]["oShipData"] = {}
 b["AddNewShipmentV3"]["oShipData"]["ReadyTime"] = a["AddNewShipmentV3"]["oShipData"]["ReadyDate"]
    
 if "CloseTime" in a["AddNewShipmentV3"]["oShipData"]:
    b["AddNewShipmentV3"]["oShipData"]["CloseDate"] = a["AddNewShipmentV3"]["oShipData"]["CloseTime"]    
 else:
    pass           
 # this will create a new dictionary (b) with new values "CloseDate" and "ReadyTime" in the starting 
 of the dictionary
 b["AddNewShipmentV3"]["oShipData"].update(a["AddNewShipmentV3"]["oShipData"])    
 return b
 
read_date_time(ship)
```

My output :

```
{'AddNewShipmentV3': {'oShipData': {'ReadyTime': '2021-01-11T12:00:00', 'CloseDate': '2021-01-11T08:12:34', 'ReadyDate': '2021-01-11T12:00:00', 'CloseTime': '2021-01-11T08:12:34', 'ServiceLevel': 'EC', 'ShipperName': 'Test 1/12/2021', 'SpecialInstructions': 'Invoice - RMA#S, 7800401086-GOOD EQUIP Pickup - DRIVER WILL NEED SHRINK WRAP FOR 2 PALLETS PLEASE CALL', 'Station': 'SLC', 'CustomerNo': '9468', 'BillToAcct': '9468', 'DeclaredType': 'LL'}}}
```

I want to achieve this task without declaring multiple empty dicts to set inner values.
I read it somewhere we can do it using pydash, but am not familiar on using that

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: updated in the post

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using defaultdict class from python collections

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
d['a']['b']['c'] = 'd'
```